# SQL consecutive occurrence of entries between a range

Tags: sql, postgresql, range

I'm trying to write a query where I need to fetch all occurrence of data between year X to year Y where the data has to be present in every year(X+1,X+2). E.g consecutive years between year X to year Y.

Right now the only solution I can think of is to use select statement that appears in year X INNER JOIN year(X+1) until Y but it is not very feasible if Y-X is a huge number.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this in SQL?
I'm currently using PostgreSQL

Thanks!

EDIT :

Sample Query: Find all magazine that is published every year from 1992 to 1995,
hence my expected output should only be A or if 1995 to 1997, it should only be B

```
------------------------------
| Magazine | Year_of_publish |
------------------------------
| A        | 1992            |
------------------------------
| B        | 1993            |
------------------------------
| A        | 1993            |
------------------------------
| A        | 1994            |
------------------------------
| A        | 1995            |
------------------------------
| B        | 1995            |
------------------------------
| B        | 1996            |
------------------------------
| B        | 1997            |
------------------------------
```

Comment: Tip: a help table containing the expected years can perhaps be useful. Do an outer join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Magazine 
from t 
where Year_of_publish between 1992 and 1995
group by Magazine
having count(distinct Year_of_publish ) = 1995-1992+1
```

Answer (score 1):

If the table in your question is called `editions`, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT e.magazine
FROM generate_series(1992, 1995) s
   JOIN editions e ON s.s = e.year_of_publish
GROUP BY e.magazine
HAVING count(*) = 1995 - 1992 + 1;
```

You have to replace all occurrences of 1992 and 1995 with the appropriate years.